# Calculate network distance from point layer to Hub layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, network, distance-matrix

I have a river network layer, a layer of 360 sampling sites and a layer of 700 facilities. I want to calculate the network distance only between sampling sites and facilities but between all sites and facilities. I have tried net.distance from the GRASS plugin which only gave me the distance between the nearest site and facility. I also tried OD-Matrix from points from the QNEAT3 plugin, but I had to union the sites with facilities and the resulting matrix is too much to handle for my computer.

Here a cutout from my map, the blue dots are the sites and the yellow squares the facilities.

[image]